# TextViews vs ListView - наивысшая производительность?

Tags: java, android, производительность

В моей программе есть большое количество последовательных текстовых элементов. Выглядит это так:

item1

item2

item3

item4

...

И есть цель отфильтровать эти элементы, чтобы на выходе получить только те, которые удовлетворяют применённой фильтрации:

item3

item4

...

Для реализации сего замысла у меня есть два пути:

1) создать Layout, где каждый элемент будет в виде TextView:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/item1"
 android:text="@string/item1"
 />
<TextView android:id="@+id/item2"
 android:text="@string/item2"
 />
<TextView android:id="@+id/item3"
 android:text="@string/item3"
 />
<TextView android:id="@+id/item4"
 android:text="@string/item4"
 />
```

Затем в коде просто скрывать те, которые не удовлетворяют фильтрации:

```
if(blahblah)item1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
if(blahblahblah)item2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

2) создать ListView и обновлять его адаптер после каждой фильтрации:

```
if(blahblah)items[0]="";
if(blahblahblah)items[1]="";

 List<String> finalList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(items));
    finalList.removeAll(Arrays.asList("", null));
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, finalList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Я порешал, что скрытие View-элемента требует меньше производительности, чем обновление целого адаптера, поэтому начал строчить Layout. Вот только количество TextView реально большое, без шуток, ровно 666 штук (я не старался, так получилось). Может ли этот факт оказать ещё более негативное влияние на производительность?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ListView` более производительное решение для такой задачи, так как он оптимизирован для вывода большого количества данных за счет переиспользования айтемов.
Фактически используется только необходимое для отображения на экране количество объектов `View` - 5-10 штук и они взаимозаменяются для списка любой длины, в то время, как в варианте с `Layout` будет создано столько объектов `View`, сколько айтемов в вашем списке, что весьма печально для памяти.

Кроме того, `ListView` имеет уже реализованные средства для работы с айтемами, в вариангте с `Layout` вам придется все реализовать самостоятельно и не факт, что у вас получится лучше, чем у разработчиков платформы.